# Fragment onswipe up hide a view

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, scrollview

I have a fragment,in which I have a calendar, text view and a listview. All these views are inside the scroll view. I need two things in that layout.

1. I want to disable the scrolling of the list view.
2. How scroll to invoke scroll view when I swipe up, I want to hide calendar and text view. And on swipe down. It shows the whole layout.

   ```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    >

   <ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
   android:id="@+id/scroll"
   >
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

           <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/compactcalendar_view_container"
               android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical">

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="New Text"
                   android:textColor="#e1dcdc"
                   android:background="#011627"
                   android:id="@+id/date_picker_text_view"
                   android:textAlignment="center" />

               <com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView
                   android:id="@+id/cvCalendar"
                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="250dp"
                   app:compactCalendarTargetHeight="250dp"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
                   app:compactCalendarBackgroundColor="#011627"
                   app:compactCalendarCurrentDayBackgroundColor="#FFC107"
                   app:compactCalendarCurrentSelectedDayBackgroundColor="#939393"
                   app:compactCalendarTextColor="#e1dcdc"
                   app:compactCalendarTextSize="12sp" />

           </LinearLayout>




      <ListView
         android:id="@+id/lvList"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:divider="#e9e9e9"
         android:dividerHeight="10dp"
         android:clickable="false"
         android:focusable="false"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         android:scrollbars="none"
         android:background="#eee"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>


    </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: For `1` you can use setScrollContainer(false)

Comment: For `2` you can use `setOnScrollChangeListener()`.

Comment: I have used setScrollContainer(false), but still the listview is scrollable

Comment: Try this `listview.setEnabled(false)`.

Comment: Is there any way to know that I have scrolled up or down?

Comment: Yes you can use `setOnScrollChangeListener()`  to achieve that. You can use first visible and last visible item to detect scrolled up/down.

Comment: after giving listview.setEnabled(false) , now the list is not scrolling, but the scrolling using scroll view is not happening

Comment: Try this `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listview)`. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646209/disable-scrolling-for-listview-and-enable-for-whole-layout]

Comment: thanks now whole view is scrolling, could you share me some example code for setOnScrollChangeListener()

Comment: I have referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview but am not getting values for the scroll

Comment: Also I have tried scrollview.setOnTouchListener(), it works fine when swiping up using ACTION_UP, it hides all the layout, when swiping down using ACTION_DOWN, the view is not getting visible