# Scroll view scrolls the list view not the layout

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

I am developing a layout which contains two listviews. when the listviews expand beyond the layout size, I want to scroll the layout but its scrolls the listview.

How to scrolls the layout instead of the listviews.

My Code:

fragment_one.xml

```
        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dip" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_nation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:background="#B29090" >
                </ListView>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_regional"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:background="#4A9C67" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: see this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646209/disable-scrolling-for-listview-and-enable-for-whole-layout

Comment: Do not put Scrollable View inside another Scrollable View(in short do not put ListView inside ScrollView)

Answer (score 0):

try NestedScrollView like,

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_nation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#B29090" >
            </ListView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_regional"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#4A9C67" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: it scrolls when i scroll in layout. but i want to scroll the layout when user trying scroll in listview

Answer (score 0):

try this, remove the `LinearLayout` use `RelativeLayout`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_nation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="#B29090" >
         </ListView>

         <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_regional"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="#4A9C67"  >
        </ListView>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```